# Windows 8. How to mirror drive on a separate machine

Tags: windows-8, backup, mirroring

I have a drive on machine 1 that I'd like to mirror onto another drive on machine 2.

Is this possible with generic Windows 8 or would I have to install special software?

Comment: What "mirror" are we talking about here? One time data backup? Clone? Or continuous backup, like RAID?

Comment: I am thinking of a semi-continuous backup of a rather large directory (and subdirs) of only modified files.  Once every hour would suit my needs.  Thanks.

Comment: I'd use [robocopy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(v=ws.11).aspx) if I wanted to just use built-in tools. Something along `robocopy "D:\" "\\IP.of.target.computer\D_Mirror\" /zb /mir /r:10 /w:5` in a batch-script (executed once every hour) should do what you want. Of course, you would also need to [share the drive on machine 2 via e.g. SMB](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770880(v=ws.11).aspx).